# dropping a table does not delete the directories on the disk

Tags: cassandra

I am just testing the `drop table` command in Cassandra 3.11. The sequence is as follows:

1. Load data worth 10gb
2. drop the table
3. on the node,

   - nodetool flush
   - nodetool clearsnapshot
   - nodetool cleanup

Still I see those SSTables directory under the data folder (using default `auto_snapshot = true`).

`select count(*) ..` shows ZERO, which is correct.

Why the folders are not getting deleted?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/41333018/246260 help?

Comment: No, I followed all the steps as mentioned in the link you provided.  Do not want to set auto_snapshot=false. My question is if we drop 10 tables, then are we live with the folders in the /data directory even if the tables are dropped? Is this normal behavior?

Comment: I believe the important point over there is that it will be the first compaction that removes your SSTables.  This I base on some rusty memories, so take it carefully.

Comment: Did your directories already disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Did you clear the snapshot of all clusters?

Clear it with

```
nodetool -h <ip address> -p <port> clearsnapshot
```